Bad comparison group in Difference in Difference models with staggered treatment and industry (not firm) fixed effects
I am working on a setting having a staggered treatment with a TWFE DID model (see Baker et al., 2022 Journal of Financial Economics).
I wonder whether the issue of using already-treated units as a comparison group arises even when the DID with staggered treatment has INDUSTRY and YEAR fixed effect (with a standard panel data at the firm-year level).
Most of the papers covering this issue analyse the TWFE specification with FIRM and YEAR fixed effects. What about the INDUSTRY fixed effect that is commonly (and maybe improperly...) used in staggered difference-in-differences research designs? Do we have the issue of bad comparisons here as well?
Thanks in advance for your help.
